# Device Support files For iOS 14.4(Beta)

Tags: ios, swift

Not able to getting Device Support files For iOS 14.4(Beta).
I have tried it to download from Xcode 12.3, but did not find.

I am using Xcode 11.3

Facing Below Error

This iPhone 7 Plus (Model 1661, 1784, 1785, 1786) is running iOS 14.4 (18D5030e), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode. An updated version of Xcode may be found on the App Store or at developer.apple.com.

Comment: Copy and rename old support files, they are compatible most of the time

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but this time it shows different error >>. An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this device. (The service is invalid.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading the latest Xcode version from https://xcodereleases.com 
I'm currently using Xcode 12.3 with an iOS 14.4 and it works

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the Same issue. Below solution worked for me.

Rename the iOS 14.3 package in device support for iOS to 14.4.

Steps 1: Applications -> Xcode

Step 2: Show package content -> Contents -> developer -> platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport

Step 3: rename 14.3 folder to 14.4.

Step 4: quit and launch Xcode.

This worked for me. try and let me know if you don't find any solution.

Comment: This is not working in my case. My iPhone Device OS is 14.4.2 and Xcode version is 11.1.